# Joining Cart entry and Product Table in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to floexible search query in hybris
I need to delete the cart entries with specific product id- I am using the below query to get the entries

```
SELECT {products.PK} FROM {Product AS products JOIN CartEntry  AS carts ON {products.PK} = {CartEntry.PRODUCT} } Where {products.PK} ='<PK of the product>'
```

I keep getting the below exception message.Is there anything i am missing

> Exception message: cannot find (visible) type for alias CartEntry within [carts:CartEntry, products:Product]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following query :

```
SELECT {products.PK} FROM {Product AS products JOIN CartEntry  AS carts ON {products.PK} = {carts.product} } Where {products.PK} ='<PK of the product>'
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing both, alias and actual name of the itemtype i.e. `{products.PK} = {CartEntry.PRODUCT}` where `products` is an alias while `CartEntry` is an actual name of the itemtype. The following will work:

```
SELECT {products.PK} FROM {Product AS products JOIN CartEntry  AS carts ON {products.PK} = {carts.product} } WHERE {products.PK} ='<PK of the product>'
```

You can also use any of the following:

```
SELECT {Product.PK} FROM {Product JOIN CartEntry ON {Product.PK} = {CartEntry.product} } WHERE {Product.PK} ='<PK of the product>'

SELECT {PK} FROM {Product}, {CartEntry}  WHERE {Product.PK} = {CartEntry.product} AND {Product.PK} ='<PK of the product>'

SELECT {PK} FROM {Product AS products}, {CartEntry AS carts}  WHERE {products.PK} = {carts.product} AND {products.PK} ='<PK of the product>'

SELECT {products.PK} FROM {Product AS products}, {CartEntry AS carts}  WHERE {products.PK} = {carts.product} AND {products.PK} ='<PK of the product>'
```